# import of cx_Oracle Module not found

Tags: python, oracle, pycharm

At point I had this cx_Oracle found in my "import cx_Oracle". It worked. Now that I am using PyCharm I get the error  that the module is not found. I can supply code if you wish.

I used the cx_Oracle example and that works as far as I can tell.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you run `python -m pip` in PyCharm?  If so, you'll find that cx_Oracle isn't installed and you might need to install it again in the version / environment inside PyCharm.  Finally, you should upgrade from cx_Oracle to the latest version, now called python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).